# A question about symmetric invertible matrix and the subspace where it is positive.

Tags: matrices

Consider a symmetric invertible matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n},$ and clearly it has $m$ positive eigenvalues (counted with multiplicities) and $n-m$ negative eigenvalues. We assume the eigenvectors corresponding to the positive (resp. negative) eigenvalues are $r_1,\cdots,r_m$ (resp. $r_{m+1},\cdots,r_n$), and $r_i$ are orthogonal. Let $P=\text{span}\{r_1,\cdots,r_m\}.$ It is obvious that $A$ is positive definite on $P,$ that is, for $x \in P\backslash\{0\},$ $x^TAx>0.$

I am wondering that whether or not $P$ has the maximal dimensions over all subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ where $A$ is positive. Suppose that there is a $(m+1)$-dimensional subspace where $A$ is positive, then we denote this subspace by $P'=\text{span}\{e_1,\cdots,e_{m+1}\},$ and $e_i$ are independent. Since there is a invertible matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ so that $Br_i=e_i$ for $i=1,\cdots,m+1.$ Thus we have
$$
e_{m+1}^TAe_{m+1}=r_{m+1}^T(B^TAB)r_{m+1},
$$
how can I prove the above expression is non-positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't know that $e_{m+1}$ is bad, because it could be equal to $r_1$, for example. The best we can say is that there is a non-zero $e\in \text{span}\{e_1,\ldots, e_{m+1}\}$ such that $e^TAe<0$, and indeed this is the case.

I claim that for any $f_1,\ldots,f_d\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $u_1,\ldots,u_{d+1}$ with the $u_i$ linearly independent, there exists $0\neq u\in \text{span}\{u_1,\ldots, u_{d+1}\}$ such that $f^T_iu=0$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d$. This is just the statement that a matrix which is wider than it is tall must have a non-zero nullspace.

Let's prove this claim by induction on $d$.

Suppose $d=1$, so we have $f_1$ and linearly independent $u_1,u_2$. If $f_1^Tu_2=0$, then we are already done. Just take $u=u_2$. Otherwise take $u=u_1-\frac{f^Tu_1}{f^Tu_2}u_2$ and directly verify that $f^1u=0$. We know $u\neq 0$ by independence.

Now suppose we have the result for $d-1$ and take $f_1,\ldots, f_d$ and $u_1, \ldots, u_{d+1}$. If it is already the case that $f_d^Tu_i=0$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d+1$, then throw away $f_d$ and $u_{d+1}$. By the inductive hypothesis, there exists $0\neq u \in \text{span}\{u_1,\ldots, u_d\}$ such that $f^T_iu=0$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d-1$. Since $f^T_du_i=0$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d$ and since $u\in \text{span}\{u_1, \ldots, u_d\}$, it follows that $f^T_du=0$ as well. If it is not already the case that $f_d^Tu_i=0$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d+1$, then there exists some $1\leqslant j\leqslant d+1$ such that $f^T_du_j\neq 0$. By reordering if necessary, we can assume $j=d+1$. For each $1\leqslant i\leqslant d$, let $u_i'=u_i-\frac{f^T_du_i}{f^T_du_{d+1}}u_{d+1}$. We can check directly that $f^T_du'_i=0$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d$ and that $u_1',\ldots,u_d'$ are still linearly independent. By the inductive hypothesis, there exists $u\in \text{span}\{u_1',\ldots,u_d'\}\subset \text{span}\{u_1,\ldots, u_{d+1}\}$ such that $f^T_iu=0$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d-1$. Again, since $u\in \text{span}\{u_1',\ldots, u_d'\}$ and $f^T_du_i'=0$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant d$, it follows that $f^T_du=0$ as well. This completes the proof of the claim.

Now, since $A$ is a real symmetric (invertible) matrix, it has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $u_1,\ldots, u_n$. Let $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n$ be the corresponding eigenvalues repeated according to multiplicity and assume $\lambda_1>\ldots>\lambda_m>0>\lambda_{m+1}>\ldots>\lambda_n$.  Then our $P=\text{span}\{u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$ is the same space you have, even if our $u_1,\ldots, u_m$ are not the same as your $r_1,\ldots,r_m$. I just wanted an orthonormal basis for convenience.

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_{m+1}$ be linearly independent. Then by the claim at the beginning of the proof, there exists $0\neq e\in \text{span}\{e_1, \ldots, e_{m+1}\}$ such that $u^T_ie=0$ for all $1\leqslant i\leqslant m$. Therefore if we write $e$ in terms of the basis $u_1,\ldots, u_n$, it must have non-zero coordinates only for the vectors $u_{m+1},\ldots, u_n$. Write $e=\sum_{j=m+1}^n a_ju_j$. Then \begin{align*} e^TAe & = \Bigl(\sum_{j=m+1}^n a_ju_j^T\Bigr)\Bigl(\sum_{j=m+1}^n a_j\lambda_j u_j\Bigr) = \sum_{j=m+1}^n a_j^2\lambda_j<0.\end{align*} We used orthonormality in the last step to deduce that $u^T_ju_i=0$ when $i,j$ are different and $u^T_iu_i=1$. Thus $\text{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$ is not a positive subspace for $A$.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, because $e_{m+1}$ may belong to $P$. Even if it doesn’t, $e_{m+1}^TAe_{m+1}$ map still be positive provided that $e_{m+1}$ is somewhat close to $P$. E.g. let $A=\operatorname{diag}(10,-1)$, $\{r_1,r_2\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$ and $e_2=(1,1)^T$. Then $e_2\not\in P=\operatorname{span}\{r_1\}$ but $e_2^TAe_2=9>0$.

At any rate, since $P'=\{e_1,\ldots,e_{m+1}\}$ is $(m+1)$-dimensional and $W=\{r_{m+1},\ldots,r_n\}$ is $(n-m)$-dimensional, we have
$$
\dim(P'\cap W)=\dim P'+\dim W-\dim(P'+W)\ge(m+1)+(n-m)-n=1.
$$
Hence there exists some nonzero vector $v\in V\cap W$ such that $v^TAv<0$, meaning that $A$ is not positive definite on $P'$.